# Does azure vnet service endpoint generates private ip for Azure services

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-network, azure-keyvault

I want to know if Azure allocates private IP address to these services like azure sql, azure keyvault etc when they are associated with vnet service endpoint?

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

No, there is a routing magic behind the scenes that makes sure your trafic to endpoint does not go to internet. Your application still uses dns name but traffic is directed internally within azure datacenter.

https://kvaes.wordpress.com/2018/06/08/taking-a-look-at-azure-service-endpoints/